# Converting xlsx to xlsm in vsto excel addin to make macros enabled

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a vsto excel addin which is used to upload the current workbook file to the cloud. The excel file can be opened from the cloud with ms-excel:ofe command, so users can work with their excel workbook, which is stored in the cloud, via their desktop office application. We want to save the file (upload the file to the cloud) only via our addin, so via our addin we have disabled all the save functionalities in excel. We do not want users to save document locally.

There is no problem with xlsx and xls files. The application flow is :

1-) User logins our cloud application from web, and opens an excel file with ms-excel:ofe command, so excel file is opened with user's desktop office application.

2-) The user makes some changes in the file and clicks our upload button(provided by vsto addin) to save document.

3-) The document is uploaded and overwritten in the cloud.

This works perfectly. However, when user adds a macro to the xlsx file, uploaded file does not contain macros. Since workbooks with macros has to be xlsm extension, me as a developer have to convert the file from xlsx to xlsm. However the only way i can do is to use

document.SaveAs(path, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled); code

But I don’t want to save file to the locally. I have to upload the file directly to the cloud with macros enabled. Is there any way to convert the workbook to support macros via vsto addin?

Comment: If you don't use `SaveAs`, how do you upload the files which don't contain macros?

Comment: Does converting your master file into a xlsm in the first phase solve your problem?